# PHP SOAP - The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to accomplish the consumption of a WebService, however, with a following error message:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation
>   'CancelaSMP'. End element 'Body' from namespace
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element
>   'param1' from namespace ''. Line 2, position 152.
>       [faultcode] => a:DeserializationFailed

This is my client's code. The content of the `$xml` variable was copied from SoapUI, and the request made there was successful:

```
  $xml = simplexml_load_file('xml.xml');
      print_r($xml_array);
        try
        {        
       $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => $trace, 'exceptions' => $exceptions));
       $response = $client->CancelaSMP($token, $xml);      

    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
       echo "Error!";
       echo $e -> getMessage ();
       echo 'Last response: '. $client->__getLastResponse();
    }   

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
    echo "</pre>";
```

**Info:`__getFunctions()`**

```
Array
(        
    [2] => CancelaSMPResponse CancelaSMP(CancelaSMP $parameters)
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP SOAP client calling function with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899706/php-soap-client-calling-function-with-parameters)